# MVC - Two classes with same reference in Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, factory

I have been searching and can't seem to find the solution. I have two views, one controller, one model, and a Factory class. However the model is not important in this question.

I want to be able to use the same variable name for both classes depending on the user's choice. For example:

```
 public class Controller  {

    public Controller(){    
        m = new Model();    
    }

     //This method is called from Factory
     /*Only one of these two will be called SetViewSwing() or SetViewKonsoll()*/
    public void SetViewSwing(){
        v = new View(this);
    }

    public void SetViewKonsoll(){
        v = new ViewKonsoll(this);
    }  
}
```

And then further down in the controller class I could do something like:

```
v.updateGui(String text);
```

So depending on if `SetViewSwing` is called or `SetViewKonsoll` is called I want to assign the class to v, which can I then use later on in my controller class to execute methods in the `viewclass` the user selected

Comment: Same as with any other Java functionality: if both classes implement the same interface you can create a reference to that interface. If they don't have anything in common (which would mean this is a suspicious design decision) then you're stuck with doing it manually; make an object reference and cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are going to do. But according to your question you want to access same view variable from controller so you need to follow this. You need a interface for this.

Declare a Common interface

```
public interface CommonView {
    void updateGui(String text);
}
```

Then you have to implement this interface to both concrete view classes

```
public class View implements CommonView {
    public View(ViewController viewController) {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateGui(String text) {
        System.out.println("Swing View");
    }
}
```

And another class

```
public class ViewKonsoll implements CommonView {

    public ViewKonsoll(ViewController viewController) {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateGui(String text) {
        System.out.println("KonsolView");
    }
}
```

Then At Controller you can define like this

```
public class ViewController {
    Model m;
    CommonView v;
    ViewController(){
        m = new Model();
    }


    public void SetViewSwing(){
        v = new View(this);

    }

    public void SetViewKonsoll(){
        v = new ViewKonsoll(this);

    }
}
```

Then you can set view from your controller or any places and call `v.updateGui(String text)` .